# Network Connection Failure: "network disconnected"

Tags: 12.10, networking, modem, huawei, cdma

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10, and have a Zantel modem (model: Huawei ec122) which is a cdma modem. I have been trying to connect to the internet but every time it loads it says "network disconnected"

Does anyone know a simple solution to this?
I would prefer a GUI solution, as I'm not very good at using the terminal.